# Python reshaping an array

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array, numpy-ndarray

This is a pretty specific question. I have this array:

```
x = np.array([[[-3, 0], [0, 0]], [[0, 0], [0, -3]], [[2, 0], [0, 0]], [[-3, 0], [0, 0]]])

[[[-3  0]
 [ 0  0]]

 [[ 0  0]
  [ 0 -3]]

 [[2  0]
  [ 0  0]]

 [[-3  0]
  [ 0  0]]]
```

I would like it to be the following.. in which the first array is in the top left corner, the next array is in the top right, third in bottom left and fourth in bottom right. My real example has more than four 2x2s in the original array... I just wanted to make a simpler example.

I have tried this:

```
x.reshape(1,4,4)
```

but this results in:

```
array([[[-3,  0,  0,  0],
    [ 0,  0,  0, -3],
    [2,  0,  0,  0],
    [-3,  0,  0,  0]]])
```

**Expected this:**

```
array([[[-3,  0,  0,  0],
    [ 0,  0,  0, -3],
    [2,  0,  -3,  0],
    [0,  0,  0,  0]]])
```

Comment: That makes no sense, there's no `2` in your array

Comment: sorry I updated it.

Answer (score 0):

Don't pass the `1`:

```
>>> x.reshape(4, 4)

array([[-3,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  0, -3],
       [ 2,  0,  0,  0],
       [-3,  0,  0,  0]])
```

Answer (score 0):

What you describe is that you want to change your innermost size of 4 into a 2x2.  Therefore, what you want is a 2x2 array of 2x2 matrices:

```
>>> x.reshape(2, 2, 2, 2)
array([[[[-3,  0],
         [ 0,  0]],

        [[ 0,  0],
         [ 0, -3]]],


       [[[ 2,  0],
         [ 0,  0]],

        [[-3,  0],
         [ 0,  0]]]])
```

If you want to *render* it as such, you'll need to write your own `__repr__` function: `numpy` only does that 2-D thing for the bottom two dimensions.
However, you *can* see the organization in this reshaping.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `np.block`. You have to provide your "corners" as elements within a list of lists:

```
x = np.array([[[-3, 0], [0, 0]], [[0, 0], [0, -3]], [[2, 0], [0, 0]], [[-3, 0], [0, 0]]])
np.block([[x[0], x[1]], [x[2], x[3]]])
```

Output

```
array([[-3,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  0, -3],
       [ 2,  0, -3,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0]])
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two axes that are changed.
You have to change the axis with `np.moveaxis`.

> **np.moveaxis(array, axis_source, axis_destination):** move axes of an array to new positions.

```
x = np.moveaxis(x, 2,0)
x = np.reshape(x,(2,2,4))
x = np.moveaxis(x, 0,1)
```

And (if you need) the final reshape:

```
x = np.reshape(x,(1,4,4))
```

Output:

```
[[[-3  0  0  0]
  [ 0  0  0 -3]
  [ 2  0 -3  0]
  [ 0  0  0  0]]]
```